# JPA Hibernate intermediary table - resubmitted

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

Rephrase of original question:

I have your typical M:M relationship, in my case think of the `User`/`Role` example:

USER, ROLE, USER_ROLE

I need a second USER_ROLE table matching up `User`s to `Role`s. I won't get into specifics as to why that is (unless you need me to), but I am looking for a way to accomplish this with JPA AND without changing up the `User` and `Role` Entities.

*I need a second USER_ROLE table to audit actions the `User` performs and which `Role` he was at the time the action was performed.*

Comment: If you use EJB for business logic you could do the auditing from there.

Comment: what JPA implementation are you using?

Comment: @Leo, I am using Hibernates implementation.

Comment: Looks like using the createNativeQuery method would do what I need... wish there was an easier JPA way of doing it.

Comment: @Dan too bad you wasn't using openJPA. They have some audit implementation (see http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.0/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_audit.html) that probably would work like a charm for you :-( for hibernate, I am not sure if envers could help you http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/

Comment: @Leo Unfort. it's not your typical audit log.  The files will change all the time according to their state.  I need to persist the files based on a scheduling service, not on how many times they're changed.

Comment: @Dan you mean, you have to monitor these files and when some of them change, then you have to reflect this into your entity? (like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#overview) ?

Comment: @Leo, the architecture requirements state that every hour the job try and upload the files associated with it.  Since the upload process uses UDP, we have no acks, which means we have to continually send the file to the upload process.  Recently though, it's changed so that each file can only be tried 3 times.  After that the file no longer gets sent to the upload process.  The auditing process needs to persist all the files that get sent to the upload process each hour.  This might consist of 200 files one hour, then 30 the next.

Comment: @Leo, thanks for sharing the link.  I am actually using the WatcherService already to monitor a directory where people drop files to.  These files are what gets persisted to the database, then use a job send them to the UPD upload process...  when I say the files state changes, it changes in the database, not on the OS.

Comment: if you've found your answer, then create an answer for your question and accept it :-) so other people can use your knowledge

Comment: @Leo, I wish it was the correct answer but sadly it is not.  I am going to rephrase my question now

Comment: Man, this is a very different new question! Even the question title does not make sense anymore!

Comment: Why don't you delete this question and ask another one?

Comment: I did (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352205/jpa-intermediary-table), but the admins locked it.  I tried explaining that the question is different only the underlying problem is the same.  Wouldn't buy it.  Still locked

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a [internal callback method](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event) that will create an entry in the audit log whenever the lifecycle of the entity changes (according to your needs).

The callback annotations are self-explanatory more or less:

```
@PrePersist void onPrePersist() {}
@PostPersist void onPostPersist() {}
@PostLoad void onPostLoad() {}
@PreUpdate void onPreUpdate() {}
@PostUpdate void onPostUpdate() {}
@PreRemove void onPreRemove() {}
@PostRemove void onPostRemove() {}
```

I quote from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PostUpdate.html) of the annotations:

> Is used to specify callback methods for the corresponding lifecycle
>   event. This annotation may be applied to methods of an entity class, a
>   mapped superclass, or a callback listener class.