# JPA intermediary table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have your typical M:M relationship, in my case think of the User/Role example:

USER, ROLE, USER_ROLE

I need a second USER_ROLE table matching up Users to Roles.  I won't get into specifics as to why that is (unless you need me to), but I am looking for a way to accomplish this with JPA *AND* without changing up the User and Role Entities.

Thoughts on how that may be accomplished?

Comment: please rephrase the orignial question. don't create a new one

Comment: It's not the same question though.  It's a different question trying to solve the same problem.